# What is the actual task of CanExecuteChanged and CommandManager.RequerySuggested?

Tags: wpf, icommand, relaycommand

I got the following code from Josh Smith's MVVM [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Can anyone provide a quick explanation of what this code actually does?

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }     
}
```

I can't understand two things:

1. what does the `CanExecuteChanged` event do?
2. what does the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` do?

The above code is from the `RelayCommand` Class from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

1. `CanExecuteChanged` notifies any command sources (like a `Button` or `MenuItem`) that are bound to that `ICommand` that the value returned by `CanExecute` has changed. Command sources care about this because they generally need to update their status accordingly (eg. a `Button` will disable itself if `CanExecute()` returns `false`).
2. The `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event is raised whenever the `CommandManager` thinks that something has changed that will affect the ability of commands to execute. This might be a change of focus, for example. Turns out that this event fires a lot.

So, in essence, what this bit of code does is ensure that whenever the command manager thinks a command's ability to execute has changed, the command will raise `CanExecuteChanged` even if it hasn't actually changed.

I actually dislike this approach to implementing `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` - it feels lazy and isn't entirely reliable. I prefer a much more fine-grained approach where the command exposes a method (eg. `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`) you can call to raise `CanExecuteChanged`, then you call this at the appropriate times from your view model.

For example, if you have a command that deletes the currently selected customer, it would have a `CanExecute()` handler that returns `true` only if there is a customer selected. You would therefore call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` whenever the selected customer changes.

Comment: really nice answer thank you so much for answering...btw,,could you please suggest me the link or any implemented example of `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`.

Comment: @Kent Boogaart: I tried Prism's `DelegateCommand`, with `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` and thought it would be a better choice over  `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested`. However, it's not working correctly, when I call `MyCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`, the according `CanMyCommandExecute` method never get called... Any suggestions?

Comment: Great answer!  Also, it doesn't seem wise to use the command manager for firing the `CanExecuteChanged` event if the command's `CanExecute()` predicate has a lot of work to do.

Answer (score 6):

- `RoutedCommands` can automatically notify if their `CanExecute` has changed, since we are implementing `ICommand` here, which the WPF system doesn't know about, we wire them to CommandManager's `RequerySuggested` event.
- Now this event is called quite often by the WPF system when the focus changes, any control is edited etc. Hence in turn `CanExecuteChanged` is raised. As your button is listening to this event it will reinvoke `CanExecute` to know the latest status.

Here is an [article](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/06/17/allowing-commandmanager-to-query-your-icommand-objects/) that might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing RaiseCanExecuteChanged()

Command Class:

```
public class CommandBase : ICommand
{
    Action _TargetExecuteMethod;
    Func<bool> _TargetCanExecuteMethod;

    public CommandBase(Action executeMethod)
    {
        _TargetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
    }

    public CommandBase(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        _TargetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
        _TargetCanExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {             

        if (_TargetCanExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            return _TargetCanExecuteMethod();
        }

        if (_TargetExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            return true;
        }                       
                    
        return false;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_TargetExecuteMethod != null)
        {
            _TargetExecuteMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding TextValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"/>
<Button Content="DoSomething" Command="{Binding DoSomething}" />
```

ViewModel class:

```
public class MyclassViewModel
{
     private string textValue;

     public String TextValue
     {
        get {                
            return textValue; 
        }
        set {               
            textValue = value;
            DoSomething.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
     }

     public CommandBase DoSomething { get; set; }

     public MyclassViewModel() //Constructor
     {            
        DoSomething = new CommandBase(OnDoSomething, CanDoSomething);            
     }

     private bool CanDoSomething()
     {
        if (TextValue?.Length > 5)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
     }

    private void OnDoSomething()
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```