# Are there any performance implications with CanExecuteCommand?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, icommand, relaycommand

What are the performance implications of using the CanExecuteCommand of the ICommand object. Is the method executed over and over again?

I need to iterate through a collection of about 200 objects based on which its decided whether the button bound to the Command should be enabled? Does the CanExecuteCommand get executed repeatedly which will make my application slow

Comment: Yes, but only if you're not prematurely optimizing.

Comment: Will your comment is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Will, I also dont completely understand. My validation is an iteration of about 200 objects - a tree view. It just checks a simple property and not very time consuming when run one time. 

My concern is if the CanExecute is fired repeatedly making the code slow. Can someone please throw some light

Comment: Will is saying the following: Your code in CanExecute should not be doing too much, because this can really be called often. But you shouldn't only worry about this, if this REALLY makes your program slow, i.e. if you can measure a degradation of performance because of too many calls to CanExecute.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `ICommand` interface is the following:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    // two methods
    bool CanExecute(object parameter);
    void Execute(object parameter);

    // one event
    event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

The `CanExecuteChanged` event should be raised any time you want to indicate that the `CanExecute` method should be checked/called by WPF. Whoever implements `ICommand` should raise the event and whoever needs to refresh the button enabled state on the GUI (the WPF system) should register for and handle the event and it calls `CanExecute`.

In Josh Smith's `RelayCommand` class, he uses WPF's built-in `CommandManager` class to raise `CanExecuteChanged`:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

In essence, WPF's `CommandManager` is a singleton that listening for all sorts of routed events: KeyUpEvent, MouseUpEvent, etc... and then tells everyone "hey something interesting happened" by raising its `RequerySuggested` event. So if you are using `RelayCommand`, your `CanExecute` will get called every time `CommandManager` thinks something interesting happened on the GUI (even if it has nothing to do with your collection). If you have 50 commands, each time you key up, it's rechecking all 50 commands. So yes, this *could* be a performance issue. However, if your logic in your `CanExecute` method is really simple, it's probably a non issue. Takeaway point: don't make database or network API calls in the `CanExecute` method.

The alternative to piggybacking off `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` to raise the  `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` event is to roll-your-own version of `RelayCommand` where you do your own checking and raise `CanExecuteChanged` manually, or look at the Prism framework's `DelegateCommand` class, where they do not tie into `CommandManager` and you have to manually raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event, which you could probably do by creating a listener for `PropertyChanged` and then raising `CanExecuteChanged` on the command.

I agree with @Will above though. `RelayCommand` will probably work over 80% of the time without issues. If you do start finding performance issues, then you can create your own version of RelayCommand or use the Prism `DelegateCommand` and raise `CanExecuteChanged` manually.

Comment: Related answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634777/what-is-the-actual-task-of-canexecutechanged-and-commandmanager-requerysuggested

Comment: Thanks Kendrick and Will, your answers summed it for me. I will put it in CanExecute and look for any performance lag. If I find one, then will look at other implementations

Answer (score 0):

For future googlers:
I have created a somewhat different command implementation. For one, it is bound to the OnPropertyChanged event of the ViewModelBase class, but it also allows the View Model to Raise the CanExecuteChanged event for all Command instances within it, regardless of a change in property, such as in the case of a One Way To Source binding scenario.
this solution is a part of the PerrypheralFrameowrk.WPF Assembly, available on nuget and codeplex. Look it up. The codeplex wiki has a detailed documentation, and so do the classes in the assembly.