# CanExecute on Relay Command not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, relaycommand

I have a simple program with a button which is binded to a Relaycommand in View model as below.I am setting the CanExecute to true based on some value (set by a timer you can find details below).My button is enabled when Status is 3,initially as I set it in constructor.But it doesn't get disabled when Status value changes on it own.I can see that disabling only when I click on it.can anybody explain why it doesn't disable on its own

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private RelayCommand mClickButtonCommand;
    private int mStatus;
    private Timer mTimer;


    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Status = 3;

        mTimer = new Timer(1000);
        mTimer.Elapsed += OnElapsed;
        mTimer.Start();
    }

    private void OnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Status == 5)
        {
            Status = 0;
        }
        Status++;
    }

    public ICommand ClickButtonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mClickButtonCommand == null)
            {
                mClickButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(OnClick, () => CanClick);
            }
            return mClickButtonCommand;
        }
    }

    private void OnClick()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
    }

    public bool CanClick
    {
        get { return Status == 3; }
    }

    public int Status
    {
        get { return mStatus; }
        set
        {
            mStatus = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Status");
            OnPropertyChanged("CanClick");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

My realy command implementation is

```
 public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{



    public RelayCommand(Action execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }
    public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #region ICommand Members

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            if (_canExecute != null)
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            if (_canExecute != null)
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute();
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members

    #region Fields

    readonly Action _execute;
    readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields
}
```

Comment: _why it doesn't disable on its own_ - are you asking why isn't the button itself getting disabled?

Comment: yes,I meant why isn't the button getting greyed out when canexecute become false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your inputs ,I have solved my problem by adding CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested in my relaycommand implementation.

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        bool result = true;

        if (_canExecute != null)
        {
            result = _canExecute();
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same way that you raise PropertyChanged events, you can raise CanExecuteChanged events ...
`ClickButtonCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();`

Comment: I didnt find RaiseCanExecuteChanged in ICommand interface but I tried this StopScanCommand.CanExecuteChanged(); but it gives error The event 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand.CanExecuteChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Comment: Sorry, I missed that ClickButtonCommand is only defined as the interface whereas mClickButtonCommand is your actual RelayCommand. Try `mClickButtonCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();`

Comment: Relay command  also doesn't have this event, see my relay command implementation.

Comment: Grah, and I also missed that you are using your own implementation of `RelayCommand`. See discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634777/what-is-the-actual-task-of-canexecutechanged-and-commandmanager-requerysuggested. Apologies for confusion, I am so used to using Prism's implementation of RelayCommand that I forget people try to reinvent it themselves.