# Forcing Reevaluation on ICommand.CanExecute

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF XAML, I've got a `Button`'s `Command` property working with an implementation of a class implementing `ICommand`.

In this implementation, I *don't* have my `CanExecuteChanged` event wired up to use `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` - I want to have control over when CanExecute is called, and using this calls it way more often than necessary.

The only other way I can get `ICommand.CanExecute` to re-evaluate is to use something like:

```
public void InvokeCanExecute()
{
    CanExecuteChanged.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

In my class implementing the `ICommand`.

This seems really nasty - am I missing something obvious? I've tried invoking the re-evaluation using `PropertyChanged` but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that - if you don't want to use `CommandManager.RequerySuggested`, which indeed might call `CanExecute` more often than necessary - you need to explicitly invoke your own `InvokeCanExecute` method in order to force the command to re-evaluate its `CanExecute` condition.

However, in most cases the `CanExecute` condition will depend on public (bindable) properties, meaning properties that raise the `PropertyChanged` event to indicate that their value has changed - it is possible to hook into this event, in order to automatically call `InvokeCanExecute` whenever one of the properties the command depends on has changed. For an example of how to implement such a command, see [this guy's blog post](http://www.mutzl.com/2014/02/a-smart-mvvm-command/) (if I'm not mistaken, this approach is implemented e.g. as part of the *MVVM Light* toolkit).

Instantiating a command using this approach would look somewhat like the following:

```
SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(() => { /* do some stuff; */ }, 
                               () => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name), 
                               this, () => Name);
```

Since the command's `CanExecute` condition (which checks whether `Name` is empty) depends on the `Name` property, it needs to be re-evaluated whenever `Name`'s content changes. You simply pass a reference to the `Name` property to the command's constructor, and `InvokeCanExecute` will automatically be called whenever the value of `Name` changes.

In theory, it is possible to go one step further and let the command itself check on which properties it depends - if you're interested in this approach, check out 
[one of my blog articles](http://www.mobilemotion.eu/?p=1424), but note that this one heavily depends on reflection so it always depends on the detailed use-case whether this approach is feasible or not. A sample implementation of this solution is included in [the MVVMbasics framework](https://github.com/mobilemotion/mvvmbasics/blob/master/Sources/MVVMbasics/MVVMbasics/Commands/BaseCommand.cs) (disclaimer: published by me). In this case, you could reduce the command initialization code to:

```
SaveCommand = CreateRelayCommand(() => { /* do some stuff; */ }, 
                                () => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name));
```

Comment: Thanks. Although if you look inside  `RelayCommand`, it's implementation of CanExecuteChanged is using `CommandManager.RequerySuggested `

Comment: You're right, although it's easily possible to implement it without using `CommandManager.RequerySuggested`, as the *MVVMbasics* implementation shows

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not really missing anything. Here's a similar question that recommends the same approach you're taking: [What is the actual task of CanExecuteChanged and CommandManager.RequerySuggested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634777/what-is-the-actual-task-of-canexecutechanged-and-commandmanager-requerysuggested).

You can make your method a little bit more robust though:

```
public void InvokeCanExecute()
{
    var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```